# JavaCC expects nothing and found nothing

Tags: javacc

I'm trying to get to the bottom of a parser problem, but to begin, I'd like to know why this happens:

```
Encountered "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
```

Here is the subset of my grammar that causes the problem:

```
options {
  STATIC = false;
  DEBUG_PARSER = true;
  DEBUG_LOOKAHEAD = true;
  LOOKAHEAD = 64;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(MyParser)
package myparser;
public class MyParser {
}
PARSER_END(MyParser)

/* skip whitespace */
SKIP : {
  " "
  | "\t"
  | "\n"
  | "\r"
}

/* other symbols */
TOKEN : {
  < COMMA: "," >
| < SEMICOLON: ";" >
| < LEFT_PAREN: "(" >
| < RIGHT_PAREN: ")" >
| < LEFT_BRACKET: "[" >
| < RIGHT_BRACKET: "]" >
| < LEFT_BRACE: "{" >
| < RIGHT_BRACE: "}" >
}

/* type specifiers */
TOKEN : {
  < TYPE_SPECIFIER:
      "void"
    | "int"
    | "float"
  >
}

/* identifiers */
TOKEN [IGNORE_CASE] : {
  <IDENTIFIER: ["_","a"-"z"] (["_","a"-"z","0"-"9"])* >
}

SimpleNode Start() : {}
{
  /* begin here */
  Declaration()
  { return jjtThis; }
}

void Declaration() : {}
{
  FunctionPrototype() <SEMICOLON>
| InitDeclaratorList() <SEMICOLON>
}

void FunctionPrototype() : {}
{
  FunctionDeclarator() <RIGHT_PAREN>
}

void FunctionDeclarator() : {}
{
  FunctionHeaderWithParameters()
| FunctionHeader()
}

void FunctionHeaderWithParameters() : {}
{
/* recursive version:
  FunctionHeader() ParameterDeclaration()
  FunctionHeaderWithParameters() <COMMA> ParameterDeclaration()
*/
  FunctionHeader() ParameterDeclaration() [FunctionHeaderWithParametersPrime()]
}

void FunctionHeaderWithParametersPrime() : {}
{
  <COMMA> ParameterDeclaration() [FunctionHeaderWithParametersPrime()]
}

void FunctionHeader() : {}
{
  FullySpecifiedType() <IDENTIFIER> <LEFT_PAREN>
}

void FullySpecifiedType() : {}
{
  TypeSpecifier()
}

void TypeSpecifier() : {}
{
  TypeSpecifierNonArray() [ArraySpecifier()]
}

void ArraySpecifier() : {}
{
/* recursive version:
  <LEFT_BRACKET> <RIGHT_BRACKET>
| <LEFT_BRACKET> ConstantExpression() <RIGHT_BRACKET>
| ArraySpecifier() <LEFT_BRACKET> <RIGHT_BRACKET>
| ArraySpecifier() <LEFT_BRACKET> ConstantExpression() <RIGHT_BRACKET>
*/
  <LEFT_BRACKET> <RIGHT_BRACKET> [ArraySpecifierPrime()]
}

void ArraySpecifierPrime() : {}
{
  <LEFT_BRACKET> <RIGHT_BRACKET> [ArraySpecifierPrime()]
}

void TypeSpecifierNonArray() : {}
{
  <TYPE_SPECIFIER>
| TypeName()
}

void TypeName() : {}
{ /* user defined type e.g struct or typedef */
  <IDENTIFIER>
}

void ParameterDeclaration() : {}
{
  ParameterDeclarator()
| ParameterTypeSpecifier()
}

void ParameterTypeSpecifier() : {}
{
  TypeSpecifier()
}

void ParameterDeclarator() : {}
{
  TypeSpecifier() <IDENTIFIER>
| TypeSpecifier() <IDENTIFIER> ArraySpecifier()
}

void InitDeclaratorList() : {}
{
/* recursive version:
  SingleDeclaration()
| InitDeclaratorList() <COMMA> <IDENTIFIER>
| InitDeclaratorList() <COMMA> <IDENTIFIER> ArraySpecifier()
| InitDeclaratorList() <COMMA> <IDENTIFIER> ArraySpecifier() <EQUAL> Initializer()
| InitDeclaratorList() <COMMA> <IDENTIFIER> <EQUAL> Initializer()
*/
  SingleDeclaration() [InitDeclaratorListPrime()]
}

void InitDeclaratorListPrime() : {}
{
  <COMMA> <IDENTIFIER> [InitDeclaratorListPrime()]
| <COMMA> <IDENTIFIER> ArraySpecifier() [InitDeclaratorListPrime()]
}

void SingleDeclaration() : {}
{
  FullySpecifiedType()
| FullySpecifiedType() <IDENTIFIER>
| FullySpecifiedType() <IDENTIFIER> ArraySpecifier()
}
```

Function declarations are working fine

```
void main(int a, int b);
```

But declaration statements, which go in the function body in the full grammar, are not working

```
float myvar;
```

The debug output for the parser and lookahead for this broken example is as follows

```
Call:   Start
  Call:   Declaration
    Call:   FunctionPrototype(LOOKING AHEAD...)
      Call:   FunctionDeclarator(LOOKING AHEAD...)
        Call:   FunctionHeaderWithParameters(LOOKING AHEAD...)
          Call:   FunctionHeader(LOOKING AHEAD...)
            Call:   FullySpecifiedType(LOOKING AHEAD...)
              Call:   TypeSpecifier(LOOKING AHEAD...)
                Call:   TypeSpecifierNonArray(LOOKING AHEAD...)
                  Visited token: <<TYPE_SPECIFIER>: "float" at line 1 column 1>; Expected token: <<TYPE_SPECIFIER>>
                Return: TypeSpecifierNonArray(LOOKAHEAD SUCCEEDED)
                Call:   ArraySpecifier(LOOKING AHEAD...)
                  Visited token: <<IDENTIFIER>: "myvar" at line 1 column 7>; Expected token: <"[">
                Return: ArraySpecifier(LOOKAHEAD FAILED)
              Return: TypeSpecifier(LOOKAHEAD SUCCEEDED)
            Return: FullySpecifiedType(LOOKAHEAD SUCCEEDED)
            Visited token: <<IDENTIFIER>: "myvar" at line 1 column 7>; Expected token: <<IDENTIFIER>>
            Visited token: <";" at line 1 column 12>; Expected token: <"(">
          Return: FunctionHeader(LOOKAHEAD FAILED)
        Return: FunctionHeaderWithParameters(LOOKAHEAD FAILED)
        Call:   FunctionHeader(LOOKING AHEAD...)
          Call:   FullySpecifiedType(LOOKING AHEAD...)
            Call:   TypeSpecifier(LOOKING AHEAD...)
              Call:   TypeSpecifierNonArray(LOOKING AHEAD...)
                Visited token: <<TYPE_SPECIFIER>: "float" at line 1 column 1>; Expected token: <<TYPE_SPECIFIER>>
              Return: TypeSpecifierNonArray(LOOKAHEAD SUCCEEDED)
              Call:   ArraySpecifier(LOOKING AHEAD...)
                Visited token: <<IDENTIFIER>: "myvar" at line 1 column 7>; Expected token: <"[">
              Return: ArraySpecifier(LOOKAHEAD FAILED)
            Return: TypeSpecifier(LOOKAHEAD SUCCEEDED)
          Return: FullySpecifiedType(LOOKAHEAD SUCCEEDED)
          Visited token: <<IDENTIFIER>: "myvar" at line 1 column 7>; Expected token: <<IDENTIFIER>>
          Visited token: <";" at line 1 column 12>; Expected token: <"(">
        Return: FunctionHeader(LOOKAHEAD FAILED)
      Return: FunctionDeclarator(LOOKAHEAD FAILED)
    Return: FunctionPrototype(LOOKAHEAD FAILED)
    Call:   InitDeclaratorList(LOOKING AHEAD...)
      Call:   SingleDeclaration(LOOKING AHEAD...)
        Call:   FullySpecifiedType(LOOKING AHEAD...)
          Call:   TypeSpecifier(LOOKING AHEAD...)
            Call:   TypeSpecifierNonArray(LOOKING AHEAD...)
              Visited token: <<TYPE_SPECIFIER>: "float" at line 1 column 1>; Expected token: <<TYPE_SPECIFIER>>
            Return: TypeSpecifierNonArray(LOOKAHEAD SUCCEEDED)
            Call:   ArraySpecifier(LOOKING AHEAD...)
              Visited token: <<IDENTIFIER>: "myvar" at line 1 column 7>; Expected token: <"[">
            Return: ArraySpecifier(LOOKAHEAD FAILED)
          Return: TypeSpecifier(LOOKAHEAD SUCCEEDED)
        Return: FullySpecifiedType(LOOKAHEAD SUCCEEDED)
      Return: SingleDeclaration(LOOKAHEAD SUCCEEDED)
      Call:   InitDeclaratorListPrime(LOOKING AHEAD...)
        Visited token: <<IDENTIFIER>: "myvar" at line 1 column 7>; Expected token: <",">
        Visited token: <<IDENTIFIER>: "myvar" at line 1 column 7>; Expected token: <",">
      Return: InitDeclaratorListPrime(LOOKAHEAD FAILED)
    Return: InitDeclaratorList(LOOKAHEAD SUCCEEDED)
    Visited token: <<IDENTIFIER>: "myvar" at line 1 column 7>; Expected token: <";">
  Return: Declaration
Return: Start
Encountered "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
```

The problem seems to be in the `SingleDeclaration` production, where it expects

```
  FullySpecifiedType()
| FullySpecifiedType() <IDENTIFIER>
```

where `FullySpecifiedType` is either a type constant (*void*, *int*, *float*) or another identifier (to facilitate user-defined types).

If I swap these lines around so that it reads

```
  FullySpecifiedType() <IDENTIFIER>
| FullySpecifiedType()
```

Then it functions as intended. Why does the order make a difference?

Comment: Can you post a minimal failing example? Or failing that, an excerpt showing the relevant productions and input.

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell Yes, I'll try to prepare something tomorrow.

Comment: The debug log is here http://pastebin.com/kuQQW23h does this help? I removed all LOOKAHEAD's and added a global LOOKAHEAD = 64;

Comment: As general advice, don't change the global lookahead. Use local lookahead.

Comment: This was a last resort debugging technique. I don't understand how there could never be any expected tokens, I was hoping that it indicated there was some standard problem.

Comment: Updated question with grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the LOOAHEAD option to 1, so that JavaCC will warn you about lookahead conflicts.

Your grammar has lookahead conflicts. The JavaCC processor should report these as warnings.  You should heed these warnings.

JavaCC, by default, uses the next token of input to make choices. See the [documentation](https://javacc.java.net/doc/docindex.html) and the [FAQ](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/) for details.  Take

```
void SingleDeclaration() : {}
{
  FullySpecifiedType()
| FullySpecifiedType() <IDENTIFIER>
| FullySpecifiedType() <IDENTIFIER> ArraySpecifier()
}
```

as an example. There is a three-way choice to be made.  The choice obviously can't be made on the basis of the kind of the next token, since any token that could start the first choice could also start the second or third.

There are two ways to fix the problem.  The best, usually, is to rewrite the grammar.

```
void SingleDeclaration() : {}
{
  FullySpecifiedType()
  [
     <IDENTIFIER>
     [
        ArraySpecifier()
     ]
  ]
}
```

The second is to use lookahead specifications.

```
void SingleDeclaration() : {}
{   
  LOOKAHEAD(FullySpecifiedType() <IDENTIFIER> "[") 
  FullySpecifiedType() <IDENTIFIER> ArraySpecifier()
| 
  LOOKAHEAD(FullySpecifiedType() <IDENTIFIER>) 
  FullySpecifiedType() <IDENTIFIER>
|
  FullySpecifiedType()
}
```

One more thing, your start production should look like this:

```
SimpleNode Start() : {}
{
  /* begin here */
  Declaration() <EOF>
  { return jjtThis; }
}
```

Comment: I am using a global LOOKAHEAD value. Do I also need to specify local LOOKAHEAD hints?

Comment: Don't use the global LOOKAHEAD option. Only use LOOKAHEAD specifications when rewriting the grammar is not a good option.

Comment: I understand it is not good for performance, but I just need it to work at the moment, then later I will return to local LOOKAHEAD hints.

Comment: My advice has nothing to do with performance and everything to do with writing a working parser.